# Get Body Content of Post In Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, request

### I submitted a body content(raw) from Postman into Laravel:

### {
"id" : "123456789"
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"params" : {
"loginId" : "24319915347",
"password" : "avc",
}
}

But, when i used request()->all(), it came up empty.

Can anyone advise how can I retrieve this body content? I cannot change how I received the content as it comes from a 3rd party.

Comment: postman has a dropdown when you select raw to allow you to pick the content type. If you set that to JSON (the default is Text) Laravel should be able to detect that correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to retrieve the request body content :

```php
$requestContent = request()->getContent();

$requestContentAsArray = json_decode($requestContent, true);
```

From the author's comment, turns out that the problem was caused by an HTTP redirect. (which must be a GET request, so the post content body was wiped out)

Comment: Thank you for the respond. But I had already tried this method, and it return me empty results

Comment: I see... Are you using HTTP or HTTPS ?

Comment: I am using https

Comment: This actually give me an idea to resolve. It was cause by Http Redirect, when it redirect, body became empty. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Updating my response with your input. Regards